# I have a background image that wont display in MOBILE even tho it displays on DESKTOP

Tags: css, image, mobile

i navigated to the location of my mobile site while on my desktop. (ex. www.mysite.com/m/index.html). On my desktop the image appears exactly the way i want it to, on mobile it does not show at all. Can anyone here tell me the possibilities of why that might happen? Here is the css associated with the image.

```
#mlogo {
    background-image: url(/m/mobileimages/mobilelogo.jpg);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-position:top;
    position: relative;
    width:100%;
    height:171px;
    text-align:center;

}
```

ive tried on a galaxy 4 and an iphone 6 .... neither displayed the image.

Comment: img is 538 width by 171 height

Answer (score 2):

try to check source code of your page goto view-source:www.mysite.com/m/index.html on your phone browser, if its displaying your source code correctly then try to navigate to your image url

Comment: Thank you. now im getting somewhere. the image says not found when i try to navigate directly to it. what would be the proper address??

Comment: url('/m/mobileimages/mobilelogo.jpg'), use single or double quote in your image url

Comment: i found out the problem (special thanks to Divyank!!)

Comment: I found out the problem (special thanks to Divyank!!). Since i was writing the code in short hand, my server was "auto-filling" the link incorrectly. instead of auto filling "http://mysite/m/mobileimages/mobilelogo.jpg". it was auto filling it in as "http://m.mysite/m/mobileimages/mobilelogo.jpg." thus making it an incorrect address. I have no "m" folder inside the "m" mobile root folder. So the first "m" is what made it an invalid link. i had to NOT USE short hand and place the full link manually to avoid the server auto filling the link.

Comment: are you using any server side language like php, asp or something ? if yes one simple function can make it more simple for short hand codes

Answer (score 0):

My server was autofilling the link address since i used short hand in my coding. the code was incorrect because of this. if you ever run into this problem. use Divyanks method to check the link. if the link is invalid you must manually enter the correct link to your image (starting with http:// and so on) to avoid the server auto filling the link address incorrectly.